# php mail() function strips off the return breaks

Tags: php, mysql, html, special-characters

this is a sample email:

```
Hello $name

thank you for joining $sitenamee

regards, the management.
```

its saved from a textarea using a simple `submit` button 
the issue I am having is when I email it using the php mail() function
I get this to my email :

```
Hello $name
thank you for joining $sitenamee
regards, the management.
```

same content which is good, but the return breaks are gone.Now IF I add  `<br>` tags to the `<textarea>` and save, it sends the email with breaks.
what would be the best way to resolve this without having to add `<br>` tags to my emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the nl2br() command to have php add the 
 tags at runtime as you send.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

```
nl2br($message);
mail($to, $subject, $message);
```